# Detect multiple broadcast on same channel

Tags: diy

I have a number of ear guards with two way radio communication. They can only be set to send and receive on the same channel, and they have the option of dividing themselves according to the ctcss standard.
The tricky thing, is that I wish to setup a second channel, that will broadcast music. This would only those on that channel hear, though at the same time have full communication between the two channels. 
Do anyone have any idea of how to pull this off? Is there a way to detect when someone tries to speak in the second channel and then stop the music? Because it's critical that the first, original channel does not get to hear music. 
It would be dead easy if the ear guards could transmit and receive on different channels. Though sadly, they can't.

Edit: I have a number of disgarded ear guards I can hack and modify to my own whim, as well as a Baofeng radio at my disposal.

Comment: Welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Comment: Note to readers in the US: ear guards = over-the-ear hearing protection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, your idea is unlikely to work.  First, in most countries broadcasting music on amateur radio bands or business communication bands is illegal.  Second, using the FM mode there is no good way to have a receiver ignore one signal when another signal arrives on the same channel, even with CTCSS.  With FM, when two signals arrive on the same channel, then the receiver picks up the louder signal, or a combination of both signals that sounds like noise.

If you were an electronics expert, it might be possible to modify the circuit of your receiver to play music from an external source, which would be cut off when a signal arrived.  But this would not be easy.